# .htaccess rewrite rules WordPress Multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I installed wordpress multisite on local wamp server: localhost/wp/

In the root of wordpress installation folder, i created a folder with custom php files: localhost/wp/demo/.

When I try to acces to this folder from : localhost/wp/demo/index.php, it's work but when i try to access from: localhost/wp/test/demo/index.php, i don't view the page but the default page from localhost/wp/test/...

My .htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?demo$ /demo/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: You said _i created a folder_ called `demo`. Then why you are trying to access it with with `test`?

Comment: demo folder is a common folder for all site, i need to acces from http://localhost/wp/demo and http://localhost/wp/test/demo... test is WPMU subdomain

Comment: So if i understand you correctly, if you create another subdomain `test2` then you want to access it like `localhost/wp/test2/demo`?

Comment: no, i want to access test2 from localhost/wp/test2 but i want access page of demo with test2 from localhost/wp/test2/demo